# How to display floating textfield depending on the text content?

Tags: text, field, itext, floating

I have a PDF template (designed using Adobe Livecycle designer), that has a subform and a textfield. The properties of those two objects is set to `float`. And the height of those objects is set to `Autofit`. All the enclosing parents heights of these objects were set to `AutoFit`.

My intention here is to increase the textfield height depending on the text content we enter into the textfield.

When I preview the template from the Adobe designer, the generated preview PDF, displays the textfield as floating (based on the test data I entered).

For our application purposes, we use iText.

Basically, we load these predefined templates, and fill in the data into those fields using iText API.

The current version of iText we use is iText 5.1.3

```
...

Document document = new Document();
document.open();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(<inputTemplate>);
ByteArrayOutputStream aStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper2 = new PdfStamper(reader, aStream2);
AcroFields form = stamper2.getAcroFields();
form.setField("<fieldname>", "<fieldvalue>");

...
```

and so on.

The PDF thus generated displays only text that fits into the size of the textbox, basically ignoring to overflow.

Hopefully, I have given enough description of the problem I am encountering. I want to dynamically embed the content and make rest of the PDF floatable. I wonder how else I can acheive this using iText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing different things.

There are two types of form technology in PDF:
- AcroForm technology: the form is described using PDF syntax, such as PDF dictionaries to describe a field using key/value pairs, and such as PDF arrays to store the coordinates of a field, and so on. If you use AcroForm technology, your requirement can't be met. You're using the wrong technology. Typically these forms are created using Adobe Acrobat, LibreOffice,...
- the XML Forms Architecture (XFA): the form is described using XML. The PDF acts as a container for the XML. Typically, these forms are created using Adobe LiveCycle Designer.

Sometimes a form uses both technologies (hybrid forms) in which case the form is defined using PDF syntax as well as XML syntax.

The only way to achieve what you want, is to use pure, dynamix XFA forms. In that case, you can't use the setField() method. Instead, you either have to use fillXfaForm() as is done in this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165
Or you have to use XFA Worker for which you can find a demo here: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xfademo/

Comment: Thanks much for your response. What my requirement is a 30 page Document, majority of it is static text with here and there data elements (like checkfields, $amount fields etc). Hence we have been using AcroFields.setField(...) approach. In some places I need to embed (inline) dynamic data (like NOTES) when available. Traditionally we attached these notes as exhibits to the end of the document, but I am exploring if I can embed inline, still retaining rest of the static text. Appreciate your thoughts on how I can accomplish this? I need to stamp page number/ totalPages as well.

Comment: Why not use annotations for the notes? (This may not be an option if you want the notes to be printed on paper.)

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific. What I meant by NOTES, is some text that I fetch from Database and render as a specific section on the PDF. Now, this data may exist, may not exist, and can be of any length. So the rendered PDF shall have the Title for section, and should display the text (if exists), otherwise continue with next section. I am working one alternative, where in I split the whole 30 page document into multiple templates. This allowed me to generate dynamically the whole page where I have these textfield place holders. And will merge this page with the rest.

Comment: The reason I am preferring static form and AcroFields is that majority of the content of PDF is statutory text, and we do not store it anywhere.